# How to get list properties?

Tags: java

I have a simple question I can't find the answer for. I have this entries added to a list:

```
Employee.add(new BackEndDeveloper(100, "Emmanuel", "Santana"));
Employee.add(new FrontEndDeveloper(100, "Luis", "Valero"));
Employee.add(new Intern(10, "Erick", "Lara"));
```

And I need to retrieve the following info:

```
"Employee ID", "First name", "Last name", "Salary", "Employee Type"
```

And I'm using something like this to call them inside 'Employee':

```
public int getEmployeeID() {
    return EmployeeID;
}
```

But how can I get Employee Type? (BackEndDev,FrontEndDev,Intern)

Comment: Your class structure is very fragile. You probably want to just make an `employeeType` field instead of subclassing. Or make an `enum` for `EmployeeTypes` and use that for the field's value.

Comment: You can use the getClass() to get the Class related to each of your Employee

Comment: there should probably be an inner property inside the subclass that specifies their type or use the getClass method

Comment: I agree with @4castle there is no need for objects of each employee type unless they are vastly different. A field level variable would collapse your implementation into something much more manageable.

Comment: You can use  InstanceOf  objects in the employee list take decision based on that

Comment: Why do you want to know the employee type? Just to show the name or something more? Maybe what you need is polymorphism. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [**getClass()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

```
BackEndDeveloper dev = new BackEndDeveloper(100, "Emmanuel", "Santana");
System.out.println(dev.getClass()); //print packageName.BackEndDeveloper
```

---

*Note: If you just want `BackEndDeveloper`, you can use `getClass().getSimpleName()`.*

```
System.out.println(dev.getClass().getSimpleName()); //print BackEndDeveloper
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question with a question, why do you need a different object for each different employee type? The question you should ask yourself when creating a subclass is what extra functionality am I going to give this new object (Remember inheritance is when you want to provide a specialization for an object, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). Could what you are trying to do not be achieved by setting a property on the Employee object instead, perhaps an Enum for EmployeeType?

```
Employee.add(new Employee(100, "Emmanuel", "Santana", EmployeeType.BackEndDeveloper));
```

you could then access it via a getter, the same way you do for id?

Whilst getClass() would technically work for the scenario provided, is the overhead of creating and maintaining extra classes worth it every time you want to add a new type of employee? As well as the risks if you wanted to change the class name but something in your implementation was dependent upon it etc.

Comment: And just to add on to this, the `EmployeeType` enum could be decorated so that it stores the human readable string that it represents as a field.

Answer (score 0):

To get back the type you can call the `getClass()`

```
List<Employee> employees;
for(Employee e : employees){
    System.out.println(e.getClass());  //will print Backend/Frontend depending on what type it is
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your aim is only to display `Employee` informations, you can simply override `toString()` method.
This way, every objects are capable of building a string of its own information; like this:

```
public class Intern {

// Fields, constructors and methods omitted

    public String toString() {
        return this.id + ", " + this.firstname + ", " + this.lastname + ", Intern";
    }

}
```

Comment: This is why the class structure is very fragile. If you wanted to change the format, you would have to modify every file. You could make helper methods in the super class, but it would be messy.

Comment: @4castle Of course it is, but you also got a format concern with the `getClass()` method because the expected value isn't exactly "human readable". IMHO, this two solutions have both pros and cons.

Comment: A better solution would be an abstract method in the Employee class. `toString` can be forgotten.